# Merging Office 365 users with AD DS?

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010, microsoft-office-365, entra-id

We have just started to deploy a Hybrid Office 365 Solution and we already had some users who signed up to Office 365 themselves, before we had full access to the domain and enabled DirSync. This has caused some issues.

At the moment we have our internal UPN suffix as `company.internal` but I have added a extra UPN suffix under Active Directory Domains and Trusts for `company.com` and set a group of users as well as a test user, to the correct external domain name. This is all working fine.

After running `DirSync` I noticed that the `In Cloud` users already existing now have two accounts, one "In Cloud" and one "Synced with AD". The synced account name/email was `username@companycom.onmicrosoft.com`.

Now to get them to merge... I did some extensive Google searches and came across two methods:

1. SMTP mail matching; `proxySMTPAdresses` matching.
2. `ImmutableID` matching to `In Cloud` account.

Neither of these worked BUT using a test account, I was able to set the `In Cloud` user to the `ImmutableID` of it's synced user and they merged perfectly fine.

I thought this method would continue to work but I was very wrong! It does not work for any other user and keeps throwing a `Unique AnchorSource ID` error.

I do not want to have to create a 'fresh' AD account for all staff that currently have an AD account just to do SMTP matching. We also have on-premises Exchange servers which is making this annoying.

Can anyone give me some advice? I am stuck!

Comment: I ended up resolving this issue, frankly I cannot remember how :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend that you follow the troubleshooting guides from Microsoft on this topic, will not copy/past them as they're long and very will formated from the source.

they have two well know knowledge base articles that will solve almost all of your problems.

1. [KB 2647098: Duplicate or invalid attributes prevent directory synchronization in Office 365](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2647098)
2. [KB 2643629: One or more objects don't sync when using the Azure Active Directory Sync tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2643629)

And of course, if those didn't work, I'd recommend you open a ticket with the Office 365 support team, they are very efficient on solving such problems.